# How to recognize text in an image using OCR

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ocr, tesseract

I have been using Tesseract OCR to recognize text in the image. It's working fine with images  in my resource bundle, but if I use `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo and use that photo to recognize the text, it's not proper and getting many special characters.

My working code for getting text from an image using Tesseract:

```
Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"eng"];                
[tesseract setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"112233.jpg"]];
[tesseract recognize];
NSLog(@" the image text is  ===\n\n\n \t %@", [tesseract recognizedText]);
```

but the same code is not working while recognizing text from a captured image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     UIImage *origiImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata"   language:@"eng"];
     [tesseract setImage:origiImage];
     [tesseract recognize];
     NSLog(@" the image text is  ===\n\n\n \t %@", [tesseract recognizedText]);
```

Comment: So you are saying that if you try to analyse the image directly (after clicking using the camera), you  do not get the correct results but if you use the same image inside your app bundle it works fine?

Comment: @AkshatSinghal no its like i take a business card image from google and i try its working but the card which i have it i take a photo and try its not working

Comment: Can you try and use the image you clicked inside the app bundle and check if it works? I suspect that the issue is with the image.